# I got an error in installing the sms a laravel package in ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql

I followed this link [Error reporting tool for Laravel: LaraBug](https://learninglaravel.net/send-sms-from-laravel-application) to send the SMS in laravel application.

I got this error installing the package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to use is:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel send-sms
```

Comment: I have a doubt php laravel runs in 8000. In ubuntu how this port will works on localhost:8000

Comment: Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5 If you want to change the port, use php artisan serve --port 8080 for example. Or set up a webserver and configure it how you like.